# Need help in configuring WAMP (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wamp

So I have been looking on the net for hours now and I can't solve my problem.
I have wamp installed (WampServer Version 3.1.7 64bit).
I want to open phpMyAdmin through wamp. (I have the phpMyAdmin5.0.2 installed and phpMyAdmin.conf is configured).
I have several php versions installed.(this was done through the process of trying to fix the solution alone).
When I try to open phpMyAdmin I get this error message: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEMaX.png .
I have tried configuring php.ini file (by de-commenting mysqli) it didn't change a thing. 
Here's my php.ini file joined in the google drive link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fQuVoh5vhRX-MHhYL3zMQ4xNkstO-4Ch/view?usp=sharing .
I have configured extension_dir tp the php/ext folder.
I have similary configured my windows path to the php/ext.
Nothing I try works. Any help is welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using WAMP, which should include all the pieces you need already working, but also have several PHP versions installed, it sounds like you're installing more than you need which is causing conflicts.

Assume you have no data in your database or web pages that you need to preserve, I suggest removing everything; get rid of WAMP and any extra Apache, PHP, or MySQL/MariaDB installations you have. Clean up (delete or move out of the way) any leftover configuration files, then reinstall WAMP. If you have trouble after installing only WAMP and no other PHP installation, then report back here details of the error. WAMP should come to you working and all ready to go, so if there is a problem, it will be helpful to start from a known base installation without extra configuration files or executable that will cause conflicts.

I'll also point out that the very top of the file you posted states that it's used only for the PHP Command Line Interface, so this is not the configuration file used by anything running through your webserver (like phpMyAdmin or your site). It's a little confusing that there are really two PHP instances (one for the command line and one that runs through the webserver), but in this case you would be looking for the file in `wamp/bin/apache/apache2.x.y/bin/php.ini`